# how can i check if the number is perfect square by not using math.sqrt

Tags: java

i want to make a program which related to this question:

> An integer that can be expressed as the square of another integer is called a perfect square, such as 4,9,16,25, etc. Write a progran that checks if a number is a perfect square.

I did built something goes like:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Q3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int a = 0;
        System.out.println("Type a number to check if it has square");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        for(a = 1;a<num;a++){ }

        if (a*a == num){
            System.out.println("Ok");
            break;
        }
        else if (a*a != num){
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
   }
}
```

So it doesn’t give what i want when i run it. What should i change or add ?

Comment: Does your `for loop` close early? I don't think its actually wrapping around your if statement.

Comment: Although the main problem is your `a` loop is empty and does nothing at all, more fundamentally your approach to tackling the problem is a really slow way to do it. If you need to test a giant number, it looks like you plan to test every single integer up to that number. That's a crazy amount of computation. A better approach is to binary search the space. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/qddoqo4vM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
class Q3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        System.out.println("Type a number to check if it has square");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        for(a = 1;a<num;a++){

             if (a*a == num){
                b = 1;
                break;
            
            }
            
      }

      if(b==1){
        System.out.println("Perfect Square");


      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Not ok");
      }

    }
}
```

Thanks for support !

Answer (score 2):

I think your for loop interpretation might be wrong, I made up something that might just work. Give this code a try.. You can make the method return a boolean too if you want.

```
static void perfectSquare(int number) {
    for (int i = 1; i < i * number; ++i) {
        // 'i' is the divisor, making sure
        // it is equal to the quotient
        if ((number % i == 0) && (number / i == i)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works completly fine ! but when i try to check and give output for non square ones, because of some misatke that i made it shows all numbers as not ok. do you have any solution for it ?

Comment: make it a boolean and when return false, print "not a square"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to brute force every number then you are on the right track but you should only print "Not ok" if all numbers in the loop have failed otherwise you may have a perfect square but "Ok" will be hidden within many "Not ok" lines. Also there is nothing in your for loop so the if statement always checks if 0*0 == num.

This looks like it may be a homework question so I won't give a full answer for you but think about how you can make this more efficient.

If you have found an integer number that matches do you need to keep going?

Do you need to check every number? (a starting point may be following the principles of a binary search)

Comment: thanks for advices. i relocate my if else lines to for loop and add a break for if block. so everything goes little bit more efficient although i cant make invisible ''Not ok'' lines before right answer. its actually my exercise not homework :D